# How to fetch array within array python

Tags: python, arrays

```
array = [['eric', '12', '12'], ['ted', '12', '102']]

n = input("name\n>>")

if n in array:
    print(array)
else:
    print("error")
```

When I input 'eric' as n I want to program to print array[0] and if I enter 'ted' I want to program to output to contents of array[1]. How do I do this?

Comment: what results do you get now.

Comment: you could use `print([arr for arr in array if n in arr])` this will print any of the arrays which have n in them. However it seems you might want a better data structure like a dict where you can store name as the key and the list as the value (assuming names are unique)

Comment: use a dictionary instead, with keys `'eric'` and `'ted'`

Comment: For a solution with dictionary see [Python: how to 'find' something in a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31169773/7851470)

Comment: Read the very next section in your Python tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You should use another data structure for that. It's just going to be easier for you. Use a hash map, a.k.a, dictionary. Like this:

```
my_dict = {'eric': ['12', '12'], 'ted': ['12', 102]}

n = input("name\n>>")

if n in my_dict:
    print(my_dict[n])
else:
    print("error")
```

By using a dictionary you are accessing its contents in O(1) time. Instead of looping through a list.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for, but this question is answered on SO allready:

```
array = [['eric', '12', '12'], ['ted', '12', '102']]

n = input("name: ")

for sub_array in array:
    if n in sub_array:
        print(sub_array)
        break
print("error")
```

Comment: What about `print("error")` if nothing match?

Comment: I added the "error" case. If the name is found then the code will exit after printing the sub_array. if the name is not found it will go to print("error")

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this:

```
for a in array:
    if n in a:
        print(a)
        break
    else if a == array[-1]:
        print('error')
```

You need to iterate over your list of lists and check if the sub-list includes `n`.

Answer (score -1):

```
array = [['eric', '12', '12'], ['ted', '12', '102']]

n = input("name\n>>")
result = None

for subarray in array:
    if n in subarray:
        print(subarray)
        result = True
if not result:
    print('Name not found')
```

But if you creating the array in the first place, I would recommend using a dictionary with names as keys instead.

Something like this:

```
example_dict = {'eric': [12,12], 'ted': [12,102]}

n = input('Name: ')

try:
    example_dict[n]
except KeyError:
    print('No such name')
```

Comment: This will print `print('Name not found')` even if there is a match.

Comment: @Guy Yeah, i just noticed that. Edited answer

Comment: Why the clumsy `result` thing when you already know for-else and just had to do it right?